# Métodos Síncrono em Assíncrono e operadores await

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, assincronismo, equações

Estou desenvolvendo um código simples em C# de equação do segundo grau apenas para eu treinar mais a lógica de programação, meu código ainda não está finalizado, porém quando dou comando `dotnet run` no VS Code, ele mostra a seguinte mensagem:

> "Este método assíncrono não possui operadores 'await' e será executado
> de modo síncrono. É recomendável o uso do operador 'await' para
> aguardar chamadas à API desbloqueadas ou do operador 'await
> Task.Run(...)' para realizar um trabalho associado à CPU em um thread
> em segundo plano."

Alguém sabe como posso resolver este problema?

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Text;
using System.Formats;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Buffers;

namespace Equação_do_segundo_grau{
    class Delta{
        public static void Main(String[]args){

            //Desenvolva uma lógica que leia os valores de A, B e C de uma equação do segundo grau e mostre o valor de Delta.

            //Declarando as variáveis
            int A, B, C;
            double Delta;

            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente quadrático
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente quadrático: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente quadrático
            A = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //
            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente linear
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente linear: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente linear
            B = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //
            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente constante
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente constante: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente constante
            C = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Delta = Math.Pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C;
            //
            //Mostrando o valor de Delta
            Console.WriteLine("O valor de Delta é: " + Delta); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: este é todo o seu código? não vejo ai `Thread`, `Task`, `async`  nem nada relacionado para justificar esse erro

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: O código ainda não está completo, pois vou fazendo aos poucos e testando, porém não consigo executar esse código por conta dessa mensagem/erro que o VS Code mostra.

"Este método assíncrono não possui operadores 'await' e será executado de modo síncrono. É recomendável o uso do operador 'await' para aguardar chamadas à API desbloqueadas ou do operador 'await Task.Run(...)' para realizar um trabalho associado à CPU em um thread em segundo plano."

Comment: O uso desse namespace [System.Threading.Tasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks?view=net-6.0) indica que o seu projeto está configurado como sendo uma aplicação de código assíncrono.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Copiei o seu código da sua pergunta e ele funcionou no meu computador. Em tese "warnings" são apenas avisos(textos em amarelo no VS code), e o código funciona com eles, eu mesmo tenho projetos com mais de 1000 warnings :)

E esse erro

> "Este método assíncrono não possui operadores 'await' e será executado de modo síncrono. É recomendável o uso do operador 'await' para aguardar chamadas à API desbloqueadas ou do operador 'await Task.Run(...)' para realizar um trabalho associado à CPU em um thread em segundo plano."

É na verdade apenas um warning, que tambem não apareceu no meu computador na hora de testar o seu código, portanto o programa deveria funcionar. POREM CONTUDO TODAVIA, é possível configurar o compilador para interpretar warnings com erros, eu pessoalmente nunca fiz isso porem é possível

Erros que impedem o seu código de rodar são vermelhos no VS code, e na print que você mandou tem um pedacinho em vermelho.
E nessa mesma print, na função Main não tem a palavra static, o que causa um erro grave e faz o seu programa não compilar...

Eu fiz umas mudanças no seu código que "arrumar" os warning que tem no seu programa

```
namespace Equação_do_segundo_grau
{
    class Delta
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            //Desenvolva uma lógica que leia os valores de A, B e C de uma equação do segundo grau e mostre o valor de Delta.

            //Declarando as variáveis
            int A = 0, B = 0, C = 0;
            double Delta;

            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente quadrático
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente quadrático: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente quadrático
            if (Console.ReadLine() is string coeficienteQuadratico)
                A = int.Parse(coeficienteQuadratico);
            //
            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente linear
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente linear: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente linear
            if (Console.ReadLine() is string coeficienteLinear)
                B = int.Parse(coeficienteLinear);
            //
            //Imprimindo na tela e solicitando ao usuário o coeficiente constante
            Console.Write("Informe o coeficiente constante: ");
            //Lendo os dados do coeficiente constante
            if (Console.ReadLine() is string coeficienteConstante)
                C = int.Parse(coeficienteConstante);

            Delta = Math.Pow(B, 2) - 4 * A * C;
            //
            //Mostrando o valor de Delta
            Console.WriteLine("O valor de Delta é: " + Delta);
        }
    }
}
```

Se o erro persistir, recomendo deletar as pastas .vs e .vscode (elas são criadas depois automaticamente quando for necessário, então não se preocupe).

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, Gabriel!

Answer (score -4):

O VS Code simplesmente não roda o código (lembrando que o código ainda não está finalizado justamente por esse problema) e mostra essa mensagem.
Realmente não sei o que tem de errado neste código! [image: Erro ao executar o código]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).